# Vite + React + TS project is not displaying on Github Pages. Console displays a 404 error msg from main.tsx. What to do?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, github, github-pages, vite

I created a Vite + React + TS project and everything works well in VSCode and in the DOM; No error messages in the code nor in the console. However, I've uploaded this project to Github and tried to host it through Github Pages but when I click the live link, I get a [blank page](https://chris-azuaje.github.io/hangman/). In the console I get an error message which says "*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*" with a reference towards the main.tsx file.

This project was created as a tutorial from YouTube. I'll provide all the links below.

[Here is a link to the YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ONUyenGnWw&t=201s&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified)

[Here is a link to my project repository](https://github.com/chris-azuaje/hangman)

**Sidenote:**
I've asked this question before on Stack Overflow and someone was able to make it work on their repository. Their Github link works and everything. Even though I made sure all of my information was the same as theirs, I still couldn't get it to work on my end. [Here is a link to their repository](https://github.com/luis-sandbox/hangman)

Any help would be much appreciated!

I've tried changing double quotes to single quotes. Don't know if that actually matters but just wanted to give it a shot but nothing happened. I also tried moving the script tag from the index.html body to the header.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.